# Why image not similar to original

Tags: node-editor

I have added aluminum material to it and i want my png logo on that. When i render the original image is in black after render it show grey. I want base material as  aluminum and on top my png logo.

[image]

What is missing any help or suggestion plz.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

it 's easier to understand if you do not think of the logo as transparent, think of the alpha channel as a mask to determine the mix of different image maps or different shaders. There is no transparency in real terms.

[image]

Comment: where my aluminum material gone its totally black.

Comment: my original image is black text matter not black background. I need background as aluminum and my png log on top